# Generating output from compose manager after setting extent and adding zooming to scale in QGIS using python

Tags: pyqgis, print-composer, qgis-2, composer-manager

I have a piece of script which is suppose to do the following:

1. Load required shape-file in proper order and zoom to layer
2. Generate image using the composer manager based on all the shape-file in the canvas, set extent and page dimension and set the required scale

Now my output file generated is not as expected. Its seems like there is some alignment problems.

Can you help me troubleshoot the problem?

I am attaching my script below.

My QGIS version is 2.8.1.

```
import ogr,os
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from qgis.core import *
import qgis.utils
import glob
import time
import math
import processing
from processing.core.Processing import Processing
from PyQt4.QtCore import QTimer
import sys
import os
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

Processing.initialize()
Processing.updateAlgsList()
OutputFileName = "ABC"    # Temprory global placeholder for filename
canvas = iface.mapCanvas()
heatmapfile = ["C:/Shapefiles/F1.shp"]
cspFile = ["C:/Shapefiles/HM.shp"]
TexLayer = "C:/Shapefiles/US_County_NAD27.shp"

for lop in range(filesLen):
    flag = 0
    currentShpFile = heatmapfile[lop]
    currentCompShpFile = cspFile[lop]
    #enter the common path for each shapefile here
    currentShpFileName = currentShpFile.strip("C:/Shapefiles/")
    #enter the common path for each shapefile here
    currentCompShpFileName = currentCompShpFile.strip("C:/Shapefiles/")

    # enter the output path here
    imageType = "png"
    OutputFileName = "C:/ImageOut/" + currentShpFileName + "." + imageType

    wbc = QgsVectorLayer(currentCompShpFile, currentCompShpFileName, 'ogr')
    wb = QgsVectorLayer(currentShpFile, currentShpFileName, 'ogr')
    wbTex = QgsVectorLayer(TexLayer, 'CountyGrid', 'ogr')
    QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(wbc)    # Add the shapefile
    QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(wb)    # Add the shapefile
    QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(wbTex)   # Add the county shapefile
    qgis.utils.iface.setActiveLayer(wbc)   # Makes wb as active shapefile
    qgis.utils.iface.zoomToActiveLayer()  # Zoom to Layer

    print "starting composer manager now"
    imageWidth_mm = 270.8
    imageHeight_mm = 297
    dpi = 300
    xmin = -104.713
    xmax = -102.530
    ymin = 30.661
    ymax = 33.055
    scaleval = 579199
    layers = iface.legendInterface().layers()
    layer0 = layers[0]
    layer1 = layers[1]
    layer2 = layers[2]

    mapRenderer = QgsMapSettings()
    layerset = [layer0.id(),layer1.id(),layer2.id()]
    mapRenderer.setLayers(layerset)
    mapRectangle = QgsRectangle(xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax)
    mapRenderer.setExtent(mapRectangle)
    mapRenderer.setOutputSize(QSize(1600,1200))


    # create a composition and pass the renderer
    comp = QgsComposition(mapRenderer)
    comp.setPaperSize(imageWidth_mm, imageHeight_mm)
    comp.setPrintResolution(dpi)
    comp.setPlotStyle(QgsComposition.Print)
    dpmm = dpi / 25.4
    width = int(dpmm * comp.paperWidth())
    height = int(dpmm * comp.paperHeight())

    # add map to the composition
    x, y = 0, 0
    w, h = imageWidth_mm, imageHeight_mm
    composerMap = QgsComposerMap(comp, x, y, w, h)
    composerMap.setNewScale(scaleval)
    comp.addItem(composerMap)

    # create image and initialise
    image = QImage(QSize(width, height), QImage.Format_ARGB32)
    image.setDotsPerMeterX(dpmm * 1000)
    image.setDotsPerMeterY(dpmm * 1000)
    image.fill(0)
    #Render
    imagePainter = QPainter(image)
    sourceArea = QRectF(0, 0, comp.paperWidth(), comp.paperHeight())
    targetArea = QRectF(0, 0, width, height)
    comp.render(imagePainter, targetArea, sourceArea)
    imagePainter.end()
    # Save image to disk (other extensions possible)
    image.save(OutputFileName, imageType)

print "Done!"
```

I am getting the following output via script which is incorrect. As you can see from the correct image below, the output generated from the script gets cropped from the bottom and gets the extra part on top
[image]

My desired output is attached below, it's also the same generated when I export image from composer manager manually

[image]

Edit: After experimenting, I found out that my composer manager/image painter starts as shown below. It unnecessarily pans across the bottom of the page

I believe if somehow this can be fixed, I might get a decent output.

[image]

Comment: Even if QGIS 2 is not supported anymore and you must stay on QGIS2, you should upgrade to QGIS 2.18.X. QGIS 2.8 is very old. Can't you upgrade to QGIS 3? The composer doesn't exit anymore, it's now called Layout.

Comment: @etrimaille I can't update to QGIS 3 for corporate reasons. Can you please help me with my problem statement. Any lead would be helpful